# Slots ignored for CoreUI's CInput

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

I guess, that I'm misunderstanding something. According to [this documentation](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#shared-props-and-slots), I came up with the following prototype code to replace the old classic syntax. But it doesn't work at all.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <CIcon name="cil-lock-locked" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="password"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Passwort"
           :isValid="false"
           invalidFeedback="hdhdh"
           v-model="enteredPassword" />
</div>

<!-- ---------------------------------------------- -->

<CInput value="lll">
    <prepend>ppp</prepend>
    <prepend-content>
        dddd
    </prepend-content>
    <label>
        dkjdjdj
    </label>
</CInput>
```

The bottom code just displays a complete empty text box. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slots are referenced with v-slot or # prefix. Try

```
<CInput value="lll">
    <template #prepend>ppp</template>
    <template #prepend-content>
        dddd
    </template>
    <template #label>
        dkjdjdj
    </template>
</CInput>
```

You have used unknown custom element (and html label) instead of slot.

Comment: Thank you very much!